# delete all documents where id start with a number Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the fastest way to get all _ids ?

I need a query to delete all documents where _id start with a number in elasticsearch.

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_2432475",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "999",
          "file" : null,
          "age" : null,
         
        }
      },
```

Comment: I don't think you can easily do that but is there any chance that you have a similar `id` field within your document? Could you share one sample document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to first copy the internal `_id` into a doc-level field (let's call it `internal_id`:

```json
POST myindex/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.internal_id = ctx._id",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

and then use a [`match_phrase_prefix` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) like so:

```json
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "internal_id": "_24"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /myindex/_delete_by_query' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [ "1", "2" ] 
    }
  }
}'
```

wild card on _id is not supported in elasticsearch, either you have to index similar key explictly into the doc or
you can update doc using  _update_by_query and add _id key into it